# using external config file for springboot in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to aws elastic beanstalk, we used to have a springboot app in jar deployed in an ec2. We store application.properties and log4j2 config files externally and to make our springboot jar use these config through command arguments (--spring.configuration.location, etc). now we want to migrate our app to elastic beanstalk, i have read through the document, but did not find a good way to achieve this, and looks like those config files has to be packed in the jar. is there a way to keep those files external to the jar in eb env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep them external to the jar using a Procfile. Your procfile has your java command to execute the JAR and load the parameters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html

Comment: thanks! I read through the document in the url you gave, it looks like that it support a custom command but how do I upload those conf files? currently i have a application.properties and a log4j2.json, should i zip them along with the jar in a zip and upload to eb? @Chris Pollard

Comment: You got it! Zip them along with the jar and upload to eb.